# ASP.NET Custom membership issue with get custom membership user -No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

Error throws when custom membership user object create.  Details error message is as below.

**Error:**

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException was caught
  Message=No parameterless constructor defined for this object. (D:\Projects\Sample\SampleMembership\web.config line 23)
  Source=System.Web
  BareMessage=No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
  Filename=D:\Projects\Sample\SampleMembership\web.config
  Line=23
  StackTrace:
       at System.Web.Configuration.ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProvider(ProviderSettings providerSettings, Type providerType)
       at System.Web.Configuration.ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProviders(ProviderSettingsCollection configProviders, ProviderCollection providers, Type providerType)
       at System.Web.Security.Membership.InitializeSettings(Boolean initializeGeneralSettings, RuntimeConfig appConfig, MembershipSection settings)
       at System.Web.Security.Membership.Initialize()
       at System.Web.Security.MembershipAdapter.get_Providers()
       at System.Web.Security.MembershipUser..ctor(String providerName, String name, Object providerUserKey, String email, String passwordQuestion, String comment, Boolean isApproved, Boolean isLockedOut, DateTime creationDate, DateTime lastLoginDate, DateTime lastActivityDate, DateTime lastPasswordChangedDate, DateTime lastLockoutDate)
       at Asys.CatalogueViewer.Membership.CustomMembershipUser..ctor(String providername, String username, Object providerUserKey, String email, String passwordQuestion, String comment, Boolean isApproved, Boolean
```

My custom membershipUser class code is as below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using  System.Web.Security;
public class CustomMembershipUser : MembershipUser
{    
    private string _webSite;
    public string WebSite
    {
        get { return _webSite; }
        set { _webSite = value; }
    }
       public CustomMembershipUser()
           {
           }
    public CustomMembershipUser(string providername,
                              string username,
                              object providerUserKey,
                              string email,
                              string passwordQuestion,
                              string comment,
                              bool isApproved,
                              bool isLockedOut,
                              DateTime creationDate,
                              DateTime lastLoginDate,
                              DateTime lastActivityDate,
                              DateTime lastPasswordChangedDate,
                              DateTime lastLockedOutDate,
                              string webSite) :
        base(providername,
                                   username,
                                   providerUserKey,
                                   email,
                                   passwordQuestion,
                                   comment,
                                   isApproved,
                                   isLockedOut,
                                   creationDate,
                                   lastLoginDate,
                                   lastActivityDate,
                                   lastPasswordChangedDate,
                                   lastLockedOutDate)
    {
        this.WebSite =webSite;
    }
}
```

Error throws when I try to create object using above custom user class(object creation code is as below)

```
CustomMembershipUser membershipUser = new CustomMembershipUser(this.Name,
              username,
             Guid.Parse(userID.ToString()),
              email,
              passwordQuestion,
              comment,
              isApproved,
              isLockedOut,
              creationDate,
              lastLoginDate,
              lastActivityDate,
              lastPasswordChangedDate,
              lastLockedOutDate, "ss");
```

Web config configuration for this is as below.

```xml
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ModelContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.Model.csdl|res://*/Data.Model.ssdl|res://*/Data.Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=GET2CODE\GET2CODE;Initial Catalog=CatalogueViewer;User Id=sa;Password=hammer;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <machineKey validationKey= "23729FFE7E16B1DD03D3BC8B45280254DA09CE2ABF5C1AC2FFD5DA04AB2521DBD7E6A8EFBE49C63DA2DA55708545A4562C75E8495415CB7B0456720652A9F160"
decryptionKey= "D643C94989E6D3A76E265AA4A565108FA727DBC7AB87EDE85F578DC78A8E407C" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES"/>

        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/></assemblies></compilation>
        <authentication mode="Forms" >
            <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
        </authentication>
        <membership defaultProvider="CustomMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
            <providers  >
                <clear/>                
                <add name="CustomMembershipProvider" type="ASys.Membership.CustomMembershipProvider"  enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" passwordFormat="Encrypted"  connectionStringName="ModelContainer"   />              
            </providers>            
        </membership>

        <profile>
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
            </providers>
        </profile>
        <roleManager enabled="false">
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
                <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/"/>
            </providers>
        </roleManager>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: The settings from web.config are not displayed, it would be very helpful to see them. In addition to CustomMembershipUser are you using also a custom membership provider? Could you tell what is the value of "this.Name" when you call the CustomMembershipUser constructor?

Comment: Could you confirm that the type ASys.Membership.CustomMembershipProvider has a public and parameterless constructor and that when you call CustomMembershipUser's contructor this.Name is equal to "CustomMembershipProvider"?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. CustomMembershipProvider doesn’t have parameterless constructor. This.Name is value is equeal to empty string.Updated issue with full web.config file.

Comment: I think you should try to pass into the CustomMembershipProvider's constructor the name of the CustomMembershipProvider as defined in the web.config ("CustomMembershipProvider") instead on this.Name

Comment: Hi andrei m,Thanks for you'r effort. Issue solved by pasing "CustomMembershipProvider" value and adding parameterless  constructor to CustomMembershipProvider.

Comment: You're welcome! Make sure you mark a reply as answer if it helps.. It will help others as well

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the name of the provider as it is declared in the membership section of the web.config when you create an instance of CustomMembersipUser. It is not recommanded to hardcode the value in the CustomMembershipProvider, instead you could use a private field that receives this value when the CustomMembershipProvider.Initialize method is called.

For example

```
public class CustomMembershipProvider: MembershipProvider
{
    private providerName = null;
    ...

    public override void Initialize(string name, NameValueCollection config)
    {
        providerName = name; // The friendly name of the provider
        ...
    }

    public override MembershipUser TestCreateUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
    {
        CustomMembershipUser membershipUser = new CustomMembershipUser(providerName,
              username,
              Guid.Parse(userID.ToString()),
              email,
              passwordQuestion,
              comment,
              isApproved,
              isLockedOut,
              creationDate,
              lastLoginDate,
              lastActivityDate,
              lastPasswordChangedDate,
              lastLockedOutDate, "ss");
        ...
    }
}
```

You can see a similar but more detailed example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tc47t75.aspx).